# Plot from dataframe formatting data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe in which the values ​​of a ranking and the date are saved in a column, it looks something like this:

`Monday 18 September 2023 12 Friday 20 October 2023 -3 Tuesday 24    October 2023 8,`

my goal since these are all scores is to format them in the following way:

`Monday 18 September 2023 12 Friday 20 October 2023 9 (12-3) Tuesday 24 October 2023 17 (9+8)` 
once this is done I would like to create a graph using matplotlib

from that's:
Monday 18 September 2023 12
Friday 20 October 2023 -3
Tuesday 24 October 2023 8,

to:
Monday 18 September 2023 12
Friday 20 October 2023 9 (12-3)
Tuesday 24 October 2023 17 (9+8)